# TypeScript - What is the syntax of an array of objects which are children of an abstract class?

Tags: arrays, typescript, abstract-class

I have this TypeScript inheritance hierachy, Person is the base abstract class.
Whereas the class Man & class Woman are descendants of the abstract Person class.
The abstract class Person has a property called _children which are an Array of the abstract Person object.
I need to add an Array of children to my Woman and Man class.
But I guess I can't add an Array of the  Person object, because it's abstract.
Instead I need to add the descendant objects Man & Woman to the Array.
Could you tell me what the syntax of this construct is?
So I need an Array which can contain Man & Woman objects.

When I try to do this:

```
private children: Person[] = [this.womanA, this.manB, this.womanD, this.manC]; 
private manD: Man = new Man(this.children, 'Lyngby');
```

I am getting the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined at Object../src/app/_models/Man.ts

```
abstract class Person {
    private _children: Person[];    
    constructor(children: Person[]) {
        this._children = children;
    }
}

export class Woman extends Person {
    private _shoesize: number;
    constructor(children: Person[], shoesize: number) {
        super(children);
        this._shoesize = shoesize;
    }
}

export class Man extends Person {
    private _favteam: string;
    constructor(children: Person[], favteam: string) {
        super(children);
        this._favteam = favteam;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I guess I can't add an Array of the Person object*: yes, you can. And you've done it, BTW, so, what's the problem?

Comment: Well Person is an abstract class, I have tried to use Person in my Angular service, I am getting an error, I have updated my question with the info.

Comment: That's because you haven't exported it (like you've done with the two subclasses), and imported it in Man.ts.

Comment: check this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8guxkl

Comment: Thank you for your response guys, I can see that it works now. Just thought I couldn't use the abstract Person class in my Array out in the code. JB Nizet actually gave my what I needed. I don't quite now how to close this question...?